Return control character as number
so I'm trying to print every keypress as an integer and character referencing to ASCII code. and it seems I can't print some of control character.
After reading antirez's booklet about his kilo text editor I managed to disable ctrl + c, z, s, q. all those will print 3 26 19 17 respectively.
But I can't seem to disable ctrl + v which by his guide I'm supposed to turning off IEXTEN as in the code below. my ctrl + v seems to return whatever in my clipboard when it's supposed to return 22.
void enableRawMode(){
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);
    atexit(disableRawMode);

    struct termios raw = orig_termios;
    
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &raw);
    
    raw.c_iflag &= ~( ICRNL | IXON );
    raw.c_lflag &= ~( ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG );

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int main(){
    enableRawMode();

    char c;
    while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'q'){
        if (iscntrl(c)){
            printf("%d\n", c);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Anyone know why this happen? any alternative solution? I ran this on WSL terminal, does it have something to do with that?

That's not the terminal driver's normal meaning of Ctl-v (it doesn't know anything about the clipboard), I think your terminal emulator implements this as a hotkey. You'll need to go to its preferences to disable this.

What terminal software are you using on what operating system?

@DiegoFerruchelli Thanks! -- As Barmar and you correctly state, it is the stack of software between the keyboard and the OP's software. Since WSL can use different Linux distributions, and in such a distribution different terminal software is available, I think it is important to know which.

Note that when you type ctrl-v the keyboard sends 4 codes: ctrl-down, v-down, v-up, and ctrl-up. Various pieces of software can be involved in interpreting those codes: terminal, shell and window manager, for example.

                Possibly                                Machine
                another                                 executing
                machine                                 your program
+------------------------------------+    +------------------------------------+
|  +------------+    +------------+  |    |  +------------+    +------------+  |
|  |            |    | Terminal   |  |    |  | Virtual    |    |            |  |
|  | User       |    | program    |  |    |  | terminal   |    | Your       |  |
|  |            |<-->|            |<-|----|->| device.    |<-->| program    |  |
|  |            |    | e.g. PuTTY |  |    |  | Part of OS |    |            |  |
|  +------------+    +------------+  |    |  +------------+    +------------+  |
+------------------------------------+    +------------------------------------+

(This is greatly simplified, and it's just the model that's relevant to the presented scenario.)
tcsetattr controls the terminal device.
But it has no effect on the program taking input from the user, which might not even be on the same machine.
Take Ctrl-C for example. The terminal program will normally send this to the other machine. The terminal device might send a SIGINT when it receives the Ctrl-C. Or it might send it raw. This you can control tcsetattr.
But Ctrl-V is different. It's the terminal program that is handling the Ctrl-V in your case. The terminal device used by your program doesn't get to see it. So this isn't something you can control tcsetattr. At best, you can alter the settings of the terminal program manually.

@ikegami great explanation, I just remove ctrl+v as paste from terminal keybinding entirely and it works. but now I have to rely on ctrl + shift + v for paste as the tradeoff.

The communication between the terminal and your program (running on the host) is bidirectional. Bytes are sent from the terminal to the host (in response to your read() call) and strings are sent from the host to the terminal (by printf()).
As @Barmar said, your terminal isn't sending the ^V character to the host, and your program never receives it.
Just for clarification: the terminal device driver is OS code that runs on your host (in this case, inside the Linux VM), and by disabling some control characters you're just telling the device driver (not the terminal itself) that it must not do any special processing of these characters before (or instead of) sending them to your process (ie. to your code). This works for control characters that are actually sent from the terminal to the host (like ^C, etc).
By the way, something is missing in your example (the orig_termios variable?).

Ctrl-V is, in tty driver (see termios(3)), the escape character that allows you to enter a Ctrl-C literally without being interpreted by the tty driver.  If you want to enter a Ctrl-V at the terminal, just double it (Ctrl-V Ctrl-V)
You can redefine it, as in termios is defined as LNEXT index (literal next) of .c_cc[] array in struct termios.  If you want to disable the use of LNEXT just
tty_config.c_cc[LNEXT] = 0;

and you will not be able to escape special terminal characters.
